# Rails Engine routes do not work without adding the engine prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

I have an engine mounted in my rails app as:

```
mount Blazer::Engine, at: "blazer"
```

Now, this get request:

```
<%= link_to "New Query", new_query_path, class: "btn btn-info" %>
```

Redirects to this:

```
blazer/assets?action=new&controller=blazer%2Fqueries
```

Instead of

```
blazer/queries/new
```

If I override the blazer engine queries view and add the

```
blazer.new_query_path
```

prefix to it, it will work fine, but without it does not work even though it worked before I rebased my dev branch onto this one.

Because there are too many commits, it's really hard to track down the problem. Does anyone have any pointers as to why this suddenly happens?

Comment: Do you have `isolate_namespace` call in your engine? Where that ERB-code is called from? From host app or inside the engine itself?

Comment: Seems like the issue was this being included in ApplicationHelper: include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers. Not sure why that would cause issues though

Comment: Strange. I used to add those helpers but in `config.to_prepare` block of the Engine itself - to have access to routes of the hosted application. In any case good it's been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` from your `module ApplicationHelper`. Credit to comment above by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3210742/rogue
[Rails Engine routes do not work without adding the engine prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490350/rails-engine-routes-do-not-work-without-adding-the-engine-prefix#comment72127863_42490350)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ovverride `Blazer::ApplicationController` in your app like this

```rb
# config/initializers/blazer.rb

module Blazer
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base; end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to mount engine at root_path

```
mount Blazer::Engine, at: '/'
```

You can auto mount engine by specifying below code in engine.rb

```
initializer 'blazer', before: :load_config_initializers do
  Rails.application.routes.append do
    mount Blazer::Engine => '/'
  end
end
```

If engine and host application has same routes then access host routes as

```
main_app.route_path
```